# Accessing with jboss7.1 admin console

Tags: jboss7.x

Im using jboss7.1 as. Not able to access my admin console page.  i already added users into user properties by using add-user.sh.

Here the interfaces changes

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Thanks in advance.

By,

Veeraprathaban

Comment: What URL are you using to access it? Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: Now able to access it. How can i create snapshot through admin-console? can u give some suggestion.

Comment: What kind of snapshot?

Comment: Its like JVM memory usage..

Comment: Ah, I don't think you can do that through the admin console.

Comment: Is there any other way to get JVM snapshot.

Comment: Sure, jconsole, VisualVM, Mission Control or any profiler should do it. For the command like you could use jmap or jstack.

Comment: James,   Now able to access jconsole. then, How can i take the snapshot using jconsole?